# Is GeoJSON included in JS native?

Tags: angular, npm, geojson

There are some places in my prject where I use GeoJSON type:

```
function drawGeoJSONPoint(
    sourceId: number,
    feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>){
}
```

Visual Code does not swear on this type and can move user to defination.

Bu when I compile  I get error:

```
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'GeoJSON'
```

What should I do to fix it?

Also nowhere is import of `GeoJSON`, is GeoJSON included in native JS?

My full code is:

```
import { Point } from "../Models/geometry/point";
import { Polygon } from "../Models/geometry/polygon";

//Point
export function geoJSONPointToPoint(point: GeoJSON.Point): Point {
  return { X: point.coordinates[0], Y: point.coordinates[1] };
}
```

Also I have tried to clear npm and reinstall package json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to install the types for `GeoJson`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/geojson

```
npm i -D @types/geojson
```

Once installed, the types will be automatically included by the compiler

Comment: Yes, I have tried, IDE can find path to this librarym but compiler not

Comment: Is it in your package.json?

Comment: Yes, there is in package.json

Comment: I guess stop all running processes of the compiler and try to build again. And double check that the package is actually installed in the local node_modules

Comment: Okay, let me time to check, and after 1-2 hours I will response here or accept your answer, you are one who answered me

Comment: How to import geojson to the page? I have added this to package json and installed

Comment: Seens it it is compiler bug, I will write here soon

Comment: You wouldnt need to import geojson to the page